# Testing Angular component with unsubscribe Error during cleanup of component

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm testing a component which subscribe router params. Every test pass and everything works fine. But if I look in the console, I can see an error:

> Error during cleanup of component ApplicationViewComponent
>   localConsole.(anonymous function) @ context.js:232

Do you know why this occurs?

**I tried removing the `unsubscribe()` from `ngOnDestroy()` method and the error disappears.**

**Is karma/jasmine supporting `unsubscribe()` automatically?**

Here is the component and tests

### Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';   
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx'

import { AppService } from 'app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private routeSubscription: Subscription;

  // Main ID
  public applicationId: string;


  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _service: AppService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routeSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.applicationId = params['id'];

      this.getDetails();
      this.getList();
    });
  }

  getDetails() {
    this._service.getDetails(this.applicationId).subscribe(
      result => {     
        console.log(result);
      },
      error => {  
        console.error(error);        
      },
      () => {
        console.info('complete');
      }
    );
  }

  getList(notifyWhenComplete = false) {
    this._service.getList(this.applicationId).subscribe(
      result => {     
        console.log(result);
      },
      error => {  
        console.error(error);        
      },
      () => {
        console.info('complete');
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

### Component spec file

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import {
  async,
  fakeAsync,
  ComponentFixture,
  TestBed,
  tick,
  inject
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  RouterTestingModule
} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {
  HttpModule
} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

// Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Service
import { AppService } from 'app.service';
import { AppServiceStub } from './app.service.stub';

let comp:    AppComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
let service: AppService;

let expectedApplicationId = 'abc123';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpModule],
      providers: [
        FormBuilder,
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            params:  Observable.of({id: expectedApplicationId})
          }
        },
        {
          provide: AppService,
          useClass: AppServiceStub
        }    
      ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  tests();
});

function tests() {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;

    service = TestBed.get(AppService);
  });


  /*
  *   COMPONENT BEFORE INIT
  */
  it(`should be initialized`, () => {
    expect(fixture).toBeDefined();
    expect(comp).toBeDefined();
  });


  /*
  *   COMPONENT INIT
  */

  it(`should retrieve param id from ActivatedRoute`, async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(comp.applicationId).toEqual(expectedApplicationId);
  }));

  it(`should get the details after ngOnInit`, async(() => {
    spyOn(comp, 'getDetails');
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(comp.getDetails).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

  it(`should get the list after ngOnInit`, async(() => {
    spyOn(comp, 'getList');
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(comp.getList).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
}
```

#### service.stub

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class AppServiceStub {
  getList(id: string) {
    return Observable.from([              
      {
        id: "7a0c6610-f59b-4cd7-b649-1ea3cf72347f",
        name: "item 1"
      },
      {
        id: "f0354c29-810e-43d8-8083-0712d1c412a3",
        name: "item 2"
      },
      {
        id: "2494f506-009a-4af8-8ca5-f6e6ba1824cb",
        name: "item 3"      
      }
    ]);
  }
  getDetails(id: string) {
    return Observable.from([      
      {        
        id: id,
        name: "detailed item 1"         
      }
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `AppServiceStub`?

Comment: Only a stub returning observables from mocked data. Added it to post.

Comment: I got exactly the same thing going on on my test ... I let you know if i found an answer

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The "Error during component cleanup" error message happens because when `ngOnDestroy()` is called, `this.routeSubscription` is undefined. This happens because `ngOnInit()` was never invoked, meaning that you never subscribed to the route. As described in the [Angular testing tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#detectchanges), the component isn't initialized fully until you call `fixture.detectChanges()` the first time.

Therefore, the correct solution is to add `fixture.detectChanges()` to your `beforeEach()` block right after the `createComponent` is called. It can be added any time after you create the fixture. Doing so will ensure that the component is fully initialized, that way component cleanup will also behave as expected.

Comment: The fact is I dont't necessarily want the `ngOnInit` to be invoked in my test.

Comment: @BlackHoleGalaxy any reason why not? If you're not fully initializing the component when you test it, then your tests aren't going to accurately test the behavior of the component.

Comment: It's in case I want to test a method in my component outside the context of the component itself. Pure unit test. After that I test the method from the component context. I separate my unit tests from intergrations ones.

Comment: @BlackHoleGalaxy In that case you probably shouldn't create the fixture with `TestBed`. If I recall correctly, `TestBed` automatically calls `ngOnDestoy` on your component when the unit test completes, so you need to make sure the component is fully initialized as part of the test.

If your component has a static method then you can unit test it separately without creating a fixture, but methods that require an instance should be tested on a fully initialized instance of the component.

Comment: in my test cases `fixture.detectChanges()` is added still I am getting the error

Comment: @AniruddhaDas Could you post your example code somewhere or open a separate question? For OP's situation, `fixture.detectChanges()` ensures that `ngOnInit()` is called and that the subscription is created. If your situation is different, then a different solution might be necessary.

Comment: In my case, I get this error because the spy I'm creating to intercept the call throwing the error (expected behaviour in the context of the test) inside `ngOnDestroy` is not working. Even simpler, this is not working: `spyOn(component, 'ngOnDestroy')`.

Comment: Works for me, Angular 5

Comment: @AniruddhaDas this error can also be triggered in tests of AComponent, where AComponent component is creating BComponent and BComponent is using unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy

Comment: @Bogdan D, agree

Comment: do it like this `  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent); component = fixture.componentInstance;  fixture.detectChanges() ` if you add `fixture.detectChanges()` before `component=` you will receive errors

Answer (score 43):

You need to refactor your method ngOnDestroy as below :

```html
ngOnDestroy() {
  if ( this.routeSubscription)
    this.routeSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Altering your code only for tests to work usually hide a problem ... I think @excaliburHisShealth answer should be the accepted one

Comment: @j3ff Which answer is that? I don't see any "excaliburHisShealth" answers here. Could you link to the answer in your comment?

Answer (score 12):

In my case destroying the component after each test solved the problem. So you could try adding this to your describe function:

```
afterEach(() => {
  fixture.destroy();
})
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm in a similar situation where I want to test a function in my component outside the context of the component itself.

This is what worked for me:

```
afterEach(() => {
  spyOn(component, 'ngOnDestroy').and.callFake(() => { });
  fixture.destroy();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

So my situation was similar, but not exactly the same:  I'm just putting this here in case someone else finds it helpful.  When unit testing with Jamine/Karma I was getting

```
 'ERROR: 'Error during cleanup of component','
```

It turns out that was because I wasn't properly handling my observables, and they didn't have an error function on them.  So the fix was adding an error function:

```
this.entityService.subscribe((items) => {
      ///Do work
},
  error => {
    this.errorEventBus.throw(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add

> teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false },

in the TestBed.configureTestingModule, it will look like this

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [<Your component here>],
            imports: [<Your imports here>],
            providers: [<Your providers here>],
            teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false },
        }).compileComponents();
    });
```

Comment: This one didnt work for me :(

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @David Brown's response the code below is what worked for me.

```
      .subscribe(res => {
          ...
        },
        error => Observable.throw(error)
      )
```

Answer (score 3):

As explained by @randomPoison, the error is triggered when the component that uses `unsubscribe` is not initialised. However, calling `fixture.detectChanges()` is a solution for when the error is in the spec file of the respective component.

But we might also be dealing with a `FooComponent` that creates `BarComponent` and `BarComponent` uses `unsubscribe` in its `ngOnDestroy`. Proper mocking must be done.

I'd suggest a different approach to the subscription cleanup, one that is declarative and won't trigger such problems. Here's an example:

```js
export class BazComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    someObservable$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe(...);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }
}
```

More on this approach [here](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0)

Answer (score 2):

You have to do 2 things, to solve this error.

1- add **fixture.detectChanges();** in beforeEach()
2 - you need to add below, so that component can be clear.

```
afterEach(() => {
        fixture.destroy();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case the error was in the template. There was error in the child component ngDestroy ,which wasn't getting destroyed as i was  trying to set readonly property. It would be worth  your time checking your child components whether they are getting destroyed properly.

Answer (score 0):

For me what fixed this error was inside of my component's ngOnDestroy, I wrapped my store dispatch and my unsubscribe in a try catch.

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
 try {
  this.store.dispatch(new foo.Bar(this.testThing()));
  if(this.fooBarSubscription) {
   this.fooBarSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
 } catch (error) {
   this.store.dispatch(new foo.Bar(this.testThing()));
  }
}
```

Comment: could you show some code, what exactly you did in your application?

Comment: @slfan try that out

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was testing a component with multiple `@Input` properties. I had to set it inside `beforeEach` block to [] `component.xyz = []` (since it was type of an array). That was the origin of an problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when I was setting one of the services variables to `undefined`. That variable holds the information (id) of currently active entity that is being edited. *In that setter method I check that if the parent entity is set* ... and that caused the error, because my tests don't set that parent entity at any point.

so the code looked like this

```
 ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subs.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
    this.xxxEditService.activeYYY = undefined; // setter checks that parent is set, otherwise throws an error
 }
```

I solved this by providing some mock entity in my test file

```
providers: [
 {
   provide: xxxEditService,
   useValue: {
     parentEntity: {} as Parent,
     activeYYY: -1   // id
   }
}
```

**TLDR**: Something crashes during the clean up (ie. null/undef references), and it might be because of non-valid presets

Answer (score 0):

I got this due to human error.

In my case, I forgot to add method `sendC`(a new method added to ABCComponent) to the list of methods of the dependent spy component. As an Example below

```js
let abcComponent: jasmine.SpyObj<ABCComponent>
///
beforeEach(async () => {

    abcComponent = jasmine.createSpyObj('ABCComponent', [
      'sendA$',
      'sendB$',
      'sendC$' // initially forgot to add and I got the Failed: [ 'Error during cleanup of component' error. after adding this, my issue is fixed.
    ])

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AComponent],
      providers: [
        AState,
        APipe,
        BPipe,
        
        { provide: ABCComponent, useValue: abcComponent },
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy },
        { provide: NavigationService, useValue: navigationServiceSpy},
      ],
      imports: [ABCModule]
    })
      .compileComponents()
      abcComponent = TestBed.inject(ABCComponent) as jasmine.SpyObj<ABCComponent>
  })
```

So checking this solved my issue and also might solve yours.!!