# Component integration test with jasmine spy returning Subscribable

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to do component integration testing (i.e. including the Angular lifecycle events), but I'm having a hard time mocking a service with Jasmine, one that exposes a `Subscribable`.

To reproduce my scenario:

1. `ng new ng-comp-tests`
2. `ng generate component my-screen`
3. `ng generate service crud`
4. `ng generate class item`

Update the class to this:

```typescript
export class Item {
  constructor(public name: string) { }
}
```

Then make the service look like this:

```typescript
export class CrudService {
  private thing = new Subject<Item>();

  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => { this.thing.next(new Item('Thing ' + Math.random())); }, 1000);
  }

  getThingObservable() {
    return this.thing.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Change the component to be like this (and include it as the main thing in the app component):

```html
<p *ngIf="!!thing">{{thing.name}}</p>
```

```typescript
export class MyScreenComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public thing: Item;
  private thingSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private service: CrudService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.thingSubscription = this.service
      .getThingObservable()
      .subscribe(t => { this.thing = t; });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.thingSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And finally, change the spec to be this:

```typescript
describe('MyScreenComponent', () => {
  let component: MyScreenComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyScreenComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    const serviceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('CrudService', {
      getThingObservable: () => new Subject<Item>().asObservable()
    });

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyScreenComponent ],
      providers: [ { provide: CrudService, useValue: serviceSpy } ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyScreenComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This will give an exception for the test:

> MyScreenComponent should create
>   `[object ErrorEvent] thrown`

The exception isn't really helpful, and the console from Chrome isn't either, because it shows this abbreviated log:

- "Failed to load ng:///DynamicTestModule/...ngfactory.js: Cross origin requests..."
- "Failed to load ng:///DynamicTestModule/...ngfactory.js: Cross origin requests..."
- "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send'...."
- "Error during cleanup of component ... Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined..."

The [top answer for a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44186041/419956) suggests I forgot to do `fixture.detectChanges()` (which prevents `ngOnInit` from firing), but as you can see I do have that in my code.

There must be something else wrong here, but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in [the `jasmine.createSpyObj(...)` documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/jasmine.html#.createSpyObj), stating about the second parameter (emphasis mine):

> Array of method names to create spies for, or **Object whose keys will be method names *and values the returnValue*.**

In your code you're providing a fake implementation for `getThingObservable` like this:

```typescript
getThingObservable: () => new Subject<Item>().asObservable()
```

With that, the `getThingObservable` spy will return *a lambda* when the component calls it, which has no `subscribe` that the component tries to do, so the `ngOnInit` fails altogether. The `ngOnDestroy` only fails as a *secondary* effect.

You should instead directly pass the returnValue, like this:

```typescript
getThingObservable: new Subject<Item>().asObservable()
```

Then, when the component calls `getThingObservable`, it wil get an actual observable, and things will be fine.

PS. You could also simplify to using `{ of } from 'rxjs/observable/of'`:

```typescript
getThingObservable: of<Item>()
```

Finally, you could also resort to [marble tests](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-marble-tests) for more control over observables in tests.